# Dropping a connection using Fiddler

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I'm trying to simulate a connection drop using fiddler to block a request completely, I used the auto responder and *drop but my application completed and didn't block the request, so I tried the following fiddler script but also got the same behavior, Can anyone help?:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) 
{
    if (oSession.uriContains("/my uri/")) {
            oSession.oRequest.pipeClient.End();
            oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
            oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseCode = 0;
            oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "0 Client Connection Dropped by script";
            oSession.state = SessionStates.Aborted;
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information; what specifically does "completed and didn't block the request" mean? Are you sure that your rule even matched?

For what it's worth, `uriContains("/my uri/")` will NEVER be `true`; URIs never contain unescaped spaces. It should be e.g. `uriContains("/my%20uri/")`.